# Equation tags for parts of alignments

Tags: math-mode, align

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[
  1+2=3
  \implies
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
    &a+b=c, \\
    &x=y+z.
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to set up *two* equation tags, one per line in the aligned environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the [empheq](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package from the [mh](http://ctan.org/pkg/mh) bundle. See code below for an example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}       % loads »amsmath«
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
  \begin{empheq}[left={1+2=3\implies\empheqlbrace}]{align}
    a+b &= c \\
    x &= y+z
  \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just a different way of obtaining the same result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \smash{
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\normalbaselineskip-.5\jot}
          {$1+2=3\implies\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\null\\\null\end{array}\right.$}}
    a+b &= c, \\
  x &= y+z.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The key here is to set the "left-hand side" separately from the "right-hand side" and align the two using some vertical movement.

Comment: Note that this works great only if the two lines have "usual" height; e.g., it breaks if they contain fractions.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late probably but, if this was [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), I would win ;) using `numcases` environment from [`cases`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cases) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{numcases}
  {1+2=3\implies}
  a+b=c,\\
  x=y+z.
\end{numcases}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

I kept `a` aligned with `x` like in the question, otherwise `&` can be used to adjust alignment as in `aligned` or `align` environments.