# nested equations numbering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, vertical-alignment

Is there a way of playing with `align`, `alignat`, `numcases` etc environments that produces aligned and numbered equations which look like this :

```
Blahblah text before equations :

      A = B  \iff  C = D             (1)

                   { C_1 = D_1       (2)
             \iff  {
                   { C_2 = D_2       (3)

             \iff  E = F             (4)

Blahblah text after equations
```

Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

---

it looks like the numcases environment from the cases package would do the job. but it seems not allowed inside an align environment. the following minimal example won't compile. with :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cases}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A = B &\iff C=D\\
&\iff 
 \begin{numcases}{}
    C_1 = D_1\\
    C_2 = D_2
  \end{numcases}\\
&\iff E=F
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

i get :

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cases/cases.sty) (./attempt.aux)
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.12 \end{align}

?
```

Comment: I'm not sure why two equations to be considered simultaneously should receive a number each.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Related: [Equation tags for parts of alignments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5978).

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A = B &\iff C = D \\
&\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{${}\iff\!\left\{\rule{0pt}{1.1\baselineskip}\right.$}}}
 \hphantom{{}\iff{}}\;\;E=F
\\
&\hphantom{{}\iff{}}\;\;G=H\\
&\iff I=J
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is just too complicated back then. Now after three years, is there a new solution? If I only have equation (2)(3) as in the above and I want: the left bracket, the align, the numbering?

Comment: @TroyWoo Look at the `empheq` package that has just what you're looking for.