# Numbering equations in cases environment separately

Tags: cases

I have a problem with separate numbering of equations. My code is:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage[subnum]{cases}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{numcases}{n=}
    y
    \begin{cases}
    x<2
    \\
    x>3
    \end{cases}
    \\
    0
    \end{numcases}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I'd like each of three cases to have their own number on its line. Can someone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve: do you want *nested* `numcases`?

Comment: similar question: [Separate labels in cases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/)

Comment: Thank you for help, but I have there two cases environments and that is why I have problem. Is there any way to number equations separately if there are two cases environments used inside each other?

Comment: I think yes, what I want might be nested numcases. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to go using some ideas from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78050/31058):

```
\begin{numcases}{n=}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}{${} y \hspace{0.3em} \left\{\rule{0pt}{1.1\baselineskip}\right.$}}}
 \hphantom{{} y \hspace{1em} {}}\;\;x<2\\
 \hphantom{{} y \hspace{1em} {}}\;\;x>3\\
0
\end{numcases}
```

The output is the following:

[image: Output]