# subequations and array in braces

Tags: numbering, braces, subequations

I need something like this:

```
\left\{
first line  (1a)
second line (1b)
third line  (1c)
\right.
```

all lines should be aligned to left

Comment: See: [Numbering equations in cases environment separately](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104202/numbering-equations-in-cases-environment-separately)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Update according to *egreg*'s commend. Thanks!)

The first example of *empheq* given by *Bernard* is invalid if omitting the *overload* option when loading *empheq* package. For the latex file provided by *Bernard*, it has no problems at all. However, when I used `\usepackage[overload]{empheq}` in IEEEtrans with a lot other packages loaded, it will freeze the `pdflatex` on my computer, I cannot see why, so I loaded it without `overload` option. Here is the version when loading `empheq` without `overload`option (`\empheqlbrace` is the big left parenthesis. `\,` is just used to add extra space; the default is too tight.):

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}[left={K(A)=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
      & (I \otimes e^A) \psi\left(A^T \oplus (-A) \right) \\
      & (e^{A^T/2} \otimes e^{A/2}) \operatorname{sinch}\left(\frac{1}{2}[A^T \oplus (-A)]\right) \\
      & \frac{1}{2}(e^{A^T} \oplus e^A) \tau\left(\frac{1}{2}[e^T \oplus (-A)]\right),
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
```

whose output looks like:
[image: demo image]

---

For a question on citations, it works out of box, e.g. see the following codes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
We refer to the subequation (\ref{eq:2}) and the whole equation (\ref{eq:all}).
\begin{subequations}
  \label{eq:all}
    \begin{empheq}[left={K(A)=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
      & (I \otimes e^A) \psi\left(A^T \oplus (-A) \right)
        \label{eq:1} \\
      & (e^{A^T/2} \otimes e^{A/2}) \operatorname{sinch}\left(\frac{1}{2}[A^T
        \oplus (-A)]\right)
        \label{eq:2}\\
      & \frac{1}{2}(e^{A^T} \oplus e^A) \tau\left(\frac{1}{2}[e^T \oplus
        (-A)]\right),
        \label{eq:3}
    \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

which gives
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While I prefer the syntax you used, I tried Bernard's example with TeX Live 2015 and it works without problems. Maybe you didn't notice the `overload` option.

Comment: I tried using this and it works fine. But how do I reference the sub equations. I tried providing sub labels, but they don't work.

Comment: @nxkryptor  Sorry I didn't check it for long time. It works out of box for me, by just using `\labe{}` for both citing the whole equation and sub equations.

Comment: Can't you just write ```\eqref{eq:2}``` instead of ```(\ref{eq:2})```?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Well, you certainly can do that if the packages support `\eqref`, which I remember comes from `amsmath`? Mostly I do use `eqref`.

Answer (score 7):

Two solutions: one with the `empheq` package and an `align` environment, another with the `subnumcases` environment from the `cases` package. I had to adjust spacing for the brace in both, as I found the default was not so good (too small in the first case, too large in the second):

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[overload]{empheq}
    \usepackage{cases} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}[left = \empheqlbrace\,]
      & a = b \\
       & c = d
    \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subnumcases}{}
    \!\! a = b \\
    \!\! c = d
    \end{subnumcases}

    \end{document}
```

[image]