# Why does numcases uses a different bracket to cases?

Tags: cases

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
Cases:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
    N + N/4  \\
    6-W_{|N|}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Numcases:
\begin{subnumcases}{}
    N +  N/4  \\
    6-W_{|N|}  
\end{subnumcases}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the sub-numbering of subnumcases but with the standard bracket of cases.

Comment: You could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165690/, possibly removing the `\,` after `\empheqlbrace`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `empheq` which is better than `cases` for this task:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Cases}
\[
\begin{cases}
    N +  N/4  \\
    6-W_{|N|}  
\end{cases}
\]
\subsubsection*{Numbered cases}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  &  N + N/4  \\
  &  6-W_{|N|}
\end{empheq}
\subsubsection*{Subnumbered cases}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  &  N + N/4  \\
  &  6-W_{|N|}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You get the same alignment if you use

```latex
\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    N +  N/4  \\
    6-W_{|N|}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]
```

for the first.

Answer (score 0):

Using for example, `numcases` instead of `cases` you will have the standard bracket. See the manual http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cases/cases.pdf pag. 2.
The size is the same of the bracket.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,verbatim}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim} 
 with numcases:
 \end{verbatim}

\begin{numcases}{}
 N + N/4  \\
 6-W_{|N|}
\end{numcases}
\begin{verbatim} 
with subnumcases:
\end{verbatim}    

\begin{subnumcases}{}
    N +  N/4  \\
    6-W_{|N|}  
\end{subnumcases}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't this make both brackets wrong? Also numbering is now wrong.

Comment: @valerie Now is it correct?

Comment: No, look at bracket, they are totally different. Also your code and image are different.

Comment: @valerie, curly braces are equal. however it seems that this fact Sebastiano emphasize with green rectangles using other tool on equation image.

Comment: @Sebastiano, i suggest you to remove green rectangle from equation image. it seem that they confuse people.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, these are the curly brackets from the numcase environment. They have a different height as in the normal case environment. The question explicitly asks for the brackets from the case environment.

Comment: @Sebastiano Look at the correct output in the other answer, you can see that the brackets look different than yours.

Comment: @Zarko Accept your precious suggestion.

Comment: @Sebastiano Do you now see the wrong numbering and different size?

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to the question is that `{cases}` has invisible "struts", and the brace covers the extent of those. With `{numcases}` the brace only covers the mathematical text (the "ink").

You can make them equal by using

```
\usepackage[casesstyle]{cases}
```

This also normalizes the math style for both to be `\displaystyle`, where the amsmath version, based on `{array}`, is `\textstyle` (with compacted fractions and operators).