# How to have equation number for the below equation

Tags: equations, align

I am trying to put the equation number for the below expression. how to do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[  \Phi_{1}= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      a(x) & x\leq \frac{1}{3} \\ 
      b(x) & x> \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{array} 
\right. \] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You can use `empheq`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258879.

Comment: Use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` instead of `\[...\]`.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. Are you looking for `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left={\Phi_{1}=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
      a(x)\;, &\quad\text{if}~ x\leq \frac{1}{3}\;, \notag\\
      b(x)\;, &\quad\text{if}~x> \frac{1}{3} \;.
\end{empheq}
\end{document}`?

Comment: Remember that `amsmath <= mathtools`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

For such equations is in `amsmath` defined environment `cases`. For its numbering you should insert in `equation` environment as stated @Henri Menke  in his comment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % <---


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\color{blue!70!black} <---  
\Phi_{1} =  
\begin{cases}
      a(x) & x\leq \frac{1}{3} \\
      b(x) & x> \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):**
If you like to have only this equation in blue color, than after `\begin{equation}` add for example `\color{blue!70!black}`, as is added now in above MWE.

**Edit (2):**
However, if you like to have all math expressions colored, than two solutions are provided in [answer of Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37319/how-do-i-get-different-colors-for-math-and-for-text) and in [answer of David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48191/is-there-a-way-to-color-only-real-math-in-pdflatex). Considering them in above MWE, you will get:

[image]

and

[image]

respectively. Difference between them is color of equation numbers.

Comment: How to change the color of the equation to blue

Comment: Load the `(x)color` package and add `\color{blue}` just after `\begin{equation}`.