# forproblem with equation numbering

Tags: numbering, lyx, subequations

I am using LyX with layout report for my thesis. I would like to have numbering on my equations but dont know how to do it. I[image]
How can I generate equation with this form. The number of this two formula should be same, but we use a and b to distinguish them

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show us what you have tried. Try to form a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165685/237192