# numbering of equations in a cases-like environment

Tags: numbering, amsmath

I'd like to get exactly the output generated by

```
\begin{gather}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 a &= b,\\ c & = d.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{gather}
```

except that I'd like separate numbers for each of the two equations.  How do I achieve this?

(edit: in response to comments)

Numcases does what I want, thank you all for your help!  The surprising thing is that numcases does what I want it to do, but it is a poor substitute for the cases environment.  Just compile the document below and look at the symbol sizes and spacing!   In other words, the answer in the linked post answers my question, but not the question in the linked post!

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{a}{b} &= b,\\ c & = d.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{gather}

\begin{numcases}{}
 \frac{a}{b} = b,\\ c  = d.
\end{numcases}

\begin{gather}
 \begin{cases}
 \frac{a}{b} = b,\\ c = d.
\end{cases}
\end{gather}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases?lq=1 help?

Comment: That can be made to work, thanks, but if there's something for the whole equation then I'd prefer that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'something for the whole equation'. Can you explain further? It looks to me as though the answers linked by @TorbjørnT. provide exactly what you need.

Comment: this answer might help with a number for the whole equation plus separate numbers for the parts: [Numbering equations in cases environment separately](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129249/579)

Comment: I recall someone pointing out here or on comp.text.tex that using the cases environment without something to the left of the curly bracket can mess up equation spacing.  Can't find the link just now. :(