# Enumerate equations in an array after a curly brace

Tags: numbering, subequations

How to enumerate two equations that go after a curly brace?
How to make the enumeration use digits and letters, so two equations have number 1.a and 1.b?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}                                                            

\begin{document}
   \begin{equation}
        A \Rightarrow 
        \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
                    B_1, \text{ or}\\
                    B_2 
        \end{array}
        \right.
   \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78043/nested-equations-numbering ?

Comment: The same post, but linked to the @egreg answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78050/14757

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`empheq`](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) provides the bracing, while `subequations` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) provides the proper numbering:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{empheq}[left=A\Rightarrow\empheqlbrace]{align}
    & B_1, \text{ or} \\
    & B_2 
  \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`cases` provides `subnumcases` (also `numcases`, see documentation for details) for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}
        \begin{subnumcases}{A \Rightarrow}
                    B_1, &  or\\
                    B_2 &
        \end{subnumcases}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found package `empheq` which is really nice.
This example is without a curly brace.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
   \begin{empheq}[left=A\Rightarrow]{align}
        &B1\\
        &B2
   \end{empheq}                                                                 
\end{document}
```

Edit: I do not how to make enumeration to be 1.a, 1.b though.