# equations overlaping equation number in cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

I'm working with a long equation in `case` environment, the problem is that the equation overlaps the equation number... any ideas on how to solve that problem.

I've thought on aligning it all to the left, tried flushleft but i can't manage it to work.

```
  \begin{numcases}{\phi(x) =}
       -\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{k}}T_0\Big(-ke^{\frac{L}{2k}}-e^{\frac{x}{k}}(k+x)+ke^{\frac{2x}{k}}+e^{\frac{L+2x}{2k}}(k-x)\Big)}{2\Big(1+e^{\frac{L}{2k}}\Big)GJ_t}\text{,} &  $x \in [0,\frac{L}{2}],$   \\
       \frac{e^{-\frac{L+2x}{2k}}T_0\Big(-ke^{\frac{3L}{2k}}+ke^{\frac{2x}{k}}+e^{\frac{L+2x}{2k}}(k+L-x)+e^{\frac{L+x}{k}}(-k+L-x)\Big)}{2\Big(1+e^{\frac{L}{2k}}\Big)GJ_t}\text{,} &  $x \in [\frac{L}{2},L].$
  \end{numcases}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: possible duplicate:  [nested equations numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78043/579)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[left={\phi(x) =\empheqlbrace}]{align}
       &-\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{k}}T_0(A)}{2\Big(1+e^{\frac{L}{2k}}\Big)GJ_t}\text{,} &  x \in \biggl[0,\frac{L}{2}\biggr],   \\
       &\frac{e^{-\frac{L+2x}{2k}}T_0(B)}{2\Big(1+e^{\frac{L}{2k}}\Big)GJ_t}\text{,} &  x \in \biggl[\frac{L}{2},L\biggr].
  \end{empheq}
  where
  \begin{align*}
A &= -ke^{\frac{L}{2k}}-e^{\frac{x}{k}}(k+x)+ke^{\frac{2x}{k}}+e^{\frac{L+2x}{2k}}(k-x) \\
B &=  -ke^{\frac{3L}{2k}}+ke^{\frac{2x}{k}}+e^{\frac{L+2x}{2k}}(k+L-x)+e^{\frac{L+x}{k}}(-k+L-x)
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is a possibility but i was trying to avoid that

Comment: @Sebas Why to avoid. This is the best possibility, keeping your readers in mind. :-)

Comment: because I've another similar system and i would have to add four more equations A, B, C and D

Answer (score 2):

There's no hope of having those long formulas in one line.

1. The denominator is the same, so you can move it in front of `\phi(x)`
2. The denominators can be split across two or three lines
3. `numcases` should not be used

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[
  left={2\bigl(1+e^{\frac{L}{2k}}\bigr)GJ_t\phi(x)=\empheqlbrace}
]{align}
&\begin{aligned}
  &-e^{-\frac{x}{k}}T_0\Bigl(-ke^{\frac{L}{2k}}-e^{\frac{x}{k}}(k+x) \\
  &\qquad+ke^{\frac{2x}{k}}+e^{\frac{L+2x}{2k}}(k-x)\Bigr),
\end{aligned}
  &  x \in \biggl[0,\frac{L}{2}\biggr],   \\[2ex]
&\begin{aligned}
  &e^{-\frac{L+2x}{2k}}T_0\Bigl(-ke^{\frac{3L}{2k}} \\
  &\qquad+ke^{\frac{2x}{k}}+e^{\frac{L+2x}{2k}}(k+L-x) \\
  &\qquad+e^{\frac{L+x}{k}}(-k+L-x)\Bigr),
\end{aligned}
  &  x \in \biggl[\frac{L}{2},L\biggr].
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]