# Using `empheq` Inside Math Environment

Tags: numbering, align, subequations, alignat, empheq

I have a system of equations, and I want to use an enumerated `cases` option -- hence I have been using `empheq`. But I want the `cases` part to use `subequations`. Let me give a MWE which should hopefully clarify things.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a &= b \label{eq:1} \\
    &=
\begin{cases}
    c_1 %\label{eq:2a}
\\  c_2 %\label{eq:2b}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Naturally, in order to make this compile, I had to comment out `\label{eq:2a}` and `\label{eq:2b}`. I have included these, because I want these two to be labelled `2a` and `2b`, respectively.

If I didn't have the first line break, ie went straight to `a = \begin{cases} ...` then I would know how to use this using `empheq`. However, `empheq` seems to only work outside of a math environment. I hoped for a version of `alignED` or `gatherED` -- but I cannot find one.

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Does [this help?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442675/how-can-i-nest-alignment-environments-together-and-get-different-equations-numbe) You can get the 2a, 2b numbering with the `subequations` environment.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for the suggestion. I did actually mention `subequations` in the OP. None of the linked ones seem to do what I am saying...? The accepted answer is closest, but still a bit off -- it is also unbelievably complicated; I just want something like "`empheqed`". As simple as requrest as it is, maybe it doesn't exist...

Comment: So you did! The question gets a lot easier if you don’t need to nest it within another `align` environment.

Comment: Yeah. I can do it without the nesting, but the nesting is causing me issues! :(

Comment: Can you measure the width of either the LHS of equation 1, and indent the cases by that amount, or the RHS of equation 2 and set it inside a box?

Comment: I guess I can use a "`width of`" type measuring. That might have to be what I do. I tried `numcases` and `subnumcases` too, but they have similar issues that they can't be embedded inside an `align` environment

Comment: Turned out to be simpler than that. Thank you. I learned something new from this.

Comment: I'm glad that I could be of such benefit to you `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!  Figuring this out took me down several rabbit holes, but it turns out there is a simpler answer than [this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442675/how-can-i-nest-alignment-environments-together-and-get-different-equations-numbe)

Buried in a footnote to the `amsmath` manual, we find this tidbit:

> The structures `align`, `alignat`, etc., are designed for top-level use and for the most part cannot be nested inside some other displayed equation structure.   The  chief  exception  is  that `align` and  most  of  its  variants  can be used inside the `gather` environment.

Although `gather` doesn’t align its contents, there is an option to `amsmath` to make it align to the left.  Then, we can introduce a horizontal phantom to align the second equation with the first.  We can now use `\tag` within the inner `align` and place a scaling brace to its left to make them cases.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5cm} % Solely to smash the image for this MWE.
\begin{gather}
  a            = b \\
  \hphantom{a} = \notag \left\{
        \begin{alignat}{1}
           &c1 \tag{2a} \\
           &c2 \tag{2b}
        \end{alignat}
      \right.
\end{gather}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample image]

I’ll leave complications such as incrementing the equation counters correctly and aligning equations with expressions of different widths on their left-hand sides as exercises for the reader.

Another option would be to introduce the sub-equation labels as `\text`.  It’s not the most elegant solution, but it involves a lot less banging heads against the design of `amsmath`.

Comment: Super, thank you! :)