# Reference an aligned equation inside a gather environment

Tags: cross-referencing, gather

I have the below code

```
\begin{gather} V(x,y) = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{aligned}
{V_x}(x,y) &= \frac{{{y^2}(12 - 2xy - {x^2})}}{{2{{(x + y)}^2}}} = 0,\\
{V_y}(x,y) &= \frac{{{x^2}(12 - 2xy - {y^2})}}{{2{{(x + y)}^2}}} = 0.
\end{aligned}\\
\Rightarrow 12-2xy-x^2 = 0\quad \text{and}\quad 12-2xy-y^2 = 0.
\end{gather}
```

How can I cross-reference the equation `\frac{{{y^2}(12 - 2xy - {x^2})}}{{2{{(x + y)}^2}}} = 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution borrows heavily (steals??) from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78050/5001) of @egreg's to the question [nested equations numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78043/5001).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{\raisebox{-1\baselineskip}{%
  $\mathllap{V(x,y) = 0\ }\Rightarrow\quad$ }}}
   \hphantom{\Rightarrow\quad}
   V_x(x,y) = \frac{y^2(12 - 2xy - x^2)}{2(x + y)^2} = 0, \\
& \hphantom{\Rightarrow\quad}
  V_y(x,y) = \frac{x^2(12 - 2xy - y^2)}{2(x + y)^2} = 0.\\[2\jot]
&\Rightarrow 12-2xy-x^2 = 0 \quad \text{and}\quad 12-2xy-y^2 = 0.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The OP has posted a follow-up request for a version of the three-equation group without a `\Rightarrow` at the start of the third line, and with the first `=` symbol in the third line aligned with the first `=` symbols in the two preceding lines. Here goes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\smash{\raisebox{-1\baselineskip}{%
    $\mathllap{V(x,y) = 0\ }\Rightarrow\quad$}}}
 \hphantom{\Rightarrow\quad}
   V_x(x,y) &= \frac{y^2(12 - 2xy - x^2)}{2(x + y)^2} = 0, \\
 \hphantom{\Rightarrow\quad}
  V_y(x,y) &= \frac{x^2(12 - 2xy - y^2)}{2(x + y)^2} = 0.\\[2\jot]
 12-2xy-x^2 &= 0 \quad \text{and}\quad 12-2xy-y^2 = 0.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful solution.

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy - You're most welcome! If you believe that I've fully answered your question, I'd appreciate if you would "accept" my answer, by clicking on the green checkmark symbol. ;-)

Comment: Done bro. BTW, if I wanted to remove the right arrow from Eq. (3) and align the first equality of that line with the equality of V(x,y) in the above line, can you still do that while keeping everything else the same?

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: I highly appreciate your efforts @Mico. However, this is not exactly what I desired. I meant to align with V(x,y) not with V_x and V_y.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to do this I'd probably use `align` and fudge the spacing...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

gather
\begin{gather}
V(x,y) = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{aligned}
{V_x}(x,y) &= \frac{{{y^2}(12 - 2xy - {x^2})}}{{2{{(x + y)}^2}}} = 0,\\
{V_y}(x,y) &= \frac{{{x^2}(12 - 2xy - {y^2})}}{{2{{(x + y)}^2}}} = 0.
\end{aligned}\\
\Rightarrow 12-2xy-x^2 = 0\quad \text{and}\quad 12-2xy-y^2 = 0.
\end{gather}


align
\begin{align}
 &&{V_x}(x,y) &= \frac{{{y^2}(12 - 2xy - {x^2})}}{{2{{(x + y)}^2}}} = 0,\\[-5pt]
V(x,y) = 0 \Rightarrow\notag\\[-5pt]
&&{V_y}(x,y) &= \frac{{{x^2}(12 - 2xy - {y^2})}}{{2{{(x + y)}^2}}} = 0.\\[5pt]
\Rightarrow&& 12-2xy-x^2 &= 0\quad \text{and}\quad 12-2xy-y^2 = 0.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```